# Exceptions while using MvxAdapter

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following setup:
An app with 2 tabs. On the second tab there is a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection. On the first tab there are controls that cause a ViewModel for the second tab to reload the ObservableCollection. It worked well until I added a custom MvxAdapter (need it for polymorphic list items). After that after each update I see the following exceptions in the application output (note that the list still reloads its values):

```
    mvx:Warning: 42.24 Exception masked during Adapter RealNotifyDataSetChanged ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
Parameter name: jobject
      at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.14-series/8e79d361/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:866 
  at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged () [0x00058] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.14-series/8e79d361/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.cs:311 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.RealNotifyDataSetChanged () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
mvx:Warning: 42.24 Exception masked during Adapter RealNotifyDataSetChanged ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
Parameter name: jobject
      at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.14-series/8e79d361/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:866 
  at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged () [0x00058] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.14-series/8e79d361/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.cs:311 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.RealNotifyDataSetChanged () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I wonder if someone can help me to find the reason why these exceptions are thrown.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ChildPage_History, null);

        listView = view.FindViewById<MvxListView> (Resource.Id.history_list);

        listView.Adapter = new CustomAdapter (this.Activity, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you have implemented an Java Interface somewhere without inheriting from `Java.Lang.Object` and just pass in `IntPtr.Zero` is that true? Can you show the code for the `CustomAdapter`?

Comment: No, I didn't implement any Java Interface. Here is the code for `CustomAdapter`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/124bbc41b5187447241d

Comment: Not sure what is going on here, but if you could make a reproducible sample and chuck it up on GitHub or somewhere similar, I'd be happy to help debugging it.

Comment: We receive these errors quite often, also.

Comment: Is there any fix to this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is caused because the `MvxListView` constructor creates a default `MvxAdapter`. When the bindings are created the default `MvxAdapter` subscribes to the collection changed event for the collection the list is bound to. However, when the `MvxListView.Adapter` is then set to the `CustomAdapter`, the original `MvxAdapter` is still subscribed to the collection as well. Eventualy the original `MvxAdapter` gets garbage collected so when the collection changes the handler is called with a disposed object and the exception shown is the result.

I solved the problem in my project by deriving my own `MvxListView` that overrides the constructor and returns the adapter, meaning there's no need to set it in OnCreateView:

```
public class MyListView : MvxListView
{
    public MyListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base(context, attrs, new CustomAdapter(context))
    {
    }
}
```

Just change the layout XML to use this class instead of `MvxListView` and the exceptions should stop.

Comment: This does not seem to be an option if your CusotmAdapter is inheriting from MvxAdapter because you need an additional item for the constructor of CusotmAdapter.

Comment: @Bytemaster - that's not the case. `MvxAdapter` has a constructor that only requires a `Context` and fills in the `IMvxAndroidBindingContext` using `MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.Current()` (which should be set during the binding inflation process). You `CustomAdapter` constructor should call this base class constructor with just the `Context`

Comment: Got it... I was able to implement it and it works perfectly.  Note that this works for both MvxListView and MvxGridView.  Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, that is the solution. Default adapter created with listview.

Answer (score 1):

This is a threading problem. You have to raise the property change of the source in the correct thread. Try to load your source in a different project and then assign it back to the property binded in the list.

Comment: This is still occurring for me, even though all work done to add items to the ObservableCollection is forced onto the UI thread.  At the same time the items in the collection are inheriting from MvxNotifyPropertyChanged and using RaiseAndSetIfChanged, so all property updates should be happening on the UI thread as well.